# What's the meaning of 'inoremap' in vimrc

Tags: vim

There is a line below in `vimrc` example file

```
inoremap Ctrl-u Ctrl-G u Ctrl-u
```

What's the meaning of `inoremap` and what's the function of this line?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `vim` `:help inoremap` is very poetic about this:

```
:ino[remap] {lhs} {rhs}         mapmode-i             :ino :inoremap
:ln[oremap] {lhs} {rhs}         mapmode-l             :ln  :lnoremap
:cno[remap] {lhs} {rhs}         mapmode-c             :cno :cnoremap
                    Map the key sequence {lhs} to {rhs} for the modes
                    where the map command applies.  Disallow mapping of
                    {rhs}, to avoid nested and recursive mappings.  Often
                    used to redefine a command.  {not in Vi}
```

Thus it makes some insert-mode mappings for <kbd>^U</kbd> that show the filename (`^G`, undo the most recent change (`u`), and scrolls the buffer upwards by half a screen (`^U`).

I have no idea why someone would want this specific sequence of commands, except to demonstrate the `inoremap` feature -- the `^U` at the refers to the meaning the command had when the definition was created, rather than calling back into the redefined `^U` mapping.

Comment: I was looking at the meaning of inoremap. (insert, no recursion map), when I bumped into this post.

Comment: Your explanation of the mapping is incorrect. <C-G>u and <C-U> have specific meanings in insert mode. <C-G>u<C-U> actually breaks the undo chain, and then clears the current line.

Answer (score 36):

For more on why the command has such a bizarre name see [this excellent description](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) between the difference between `map` and `noremap`. Really good to know!

To summarise that article, here's a choice quote:

> One downside of the `*map` commands is the danger of recursing...
>
> Vim offers another set of mapping commands that will not take mappings
>   into account when they perform their actions.

So `noremap` came about to avoid horrible recursion of mappings like

```
:nmap dd O<esc>jddk
```

where the `dd` in the right-hand side of the map recurses back to the left-hand side definition of the map, and Vim gets stuck in an infinite loop!

Comment: That article is great, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I also wondered about this. See [http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-*Tutorial*(Part_1)#Insert_mode_maps](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)#Insert_mode_maps) :

### Insert mode maps

To map keys that work only in the insert and replace modes, use the 'imap' or 'inoremap' command.

Example: The following command maps  to insert the directory name of the current buffer:

```
:inoremap <F2> <C-R>=expand('%:p:h')<CR>
```

To display the currently defined insert mode maps, use the 'imap' command without any argument:

```
:imap
```

To remove a keymap from insert mode, use the ':iunmap' command. For example, the following command removes the insert mode map for .

```
:iunmap <F2>
```

As printable keys insert a character in the current buffer in insert mode, you should use non-printable keys to create insert mode maps. Some examples for non-printable keys include the function keys , keys prefixed with the Ctrl or Alt key.

[snip]

---

So, for example, in my ~/.vimrc I have

```
inoremap jk <ESC>
inoremap jj <Esc>
```

which when pressed in Insert mode return me to Normal mode.