# How to make js completion pop up automatically in HTML files?

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, vim-plugin

There are two ways to use tern_for_vim plugin in HTML files as the webpage say.

[use tern_for_vim plugin in HTML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792956/using-tern-for-vim-plugin-in-html-files)

Both method can work ,both of them can't make js completion menu pop up automatically.

Method1:

```
1.vim test.html
2.:setlocal omnifunc=tern#Complete
3.To input `<C-X><C-O>` after `document.`
```

Now js completion pop up.
Two issues remain for this method.
1.To write `setlocal omnifunc=tern#Complete`  in .vimrc can't work.
Why?

2.How to make js completion menu pop up automatically after  `document.` ,instead of input `<C-X><C-O>`?

Method2:

```
sudo cp .vim/bundle/tern_for_vim/after/ftplugin/javascript_tern.vim   .vim/bundle/tern_for_vim/after/ftplugin/html_tern.vim
```

You should input `<C-X><C-O>` after `document.`  in order to call  js completion menu for your html file edited.

The js completion menu for js file edited can't pop up after `document.` automatically.

1.How to make js completion menu pop up automatically after  `document.` ,instead of input `<C-X><C-O>`? (same as in Method1 the second item.)

Comment: from my point of view your question is totally unclear

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5169638/4989460

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5169683/1684254)  is a answer to the same question.

You can use a plugin like [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) to get automatic code completion as you type.

2015 Edit: I personally use [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) now.

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you're using `Method 2` and it's working using `<C-X><C-O>`

you're gonna need `inoremap` to do this , see : [What's the meaning of 'inoremap' in vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221769/whats-the-meaning-of-inoremap-in-vimrc)

and since `Tern for Vim` is hooked to `omni completion` ( as https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim ) , you can modify it's key mapping to behave like you want.

from the documentation : http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ft-javascript-omni

> You can use of  in mapping to have the popup menu used when
>   typing a character and some condition is met.  For example, for typing
>   a dot:

```
inoremap <expr> . MayComplete()
func MayComplete()
    if (can complete)
      return ".\<C-X>\<C-O>"
    endif
    return '.'
endfunc
```

Openning `vim` and typing this in command mode will do the trick :

```
:inoremap <expr> . ".\<C-X>\<C-O>"
```

this basically turns the `.` into a trigger to fire up `<CTRL-X> <CTRL-O>`

but it's better to put the `:map` commands into `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}_mappings.vim` . (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`.)

and this is for general `vim` key mapping : [http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-*Tutorial*(Part_1)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1))

check this to see it working : https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6hRZ.jpg

PS : i used `Pathogen` to install `Tern for Vim` ( https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen )

i hope this answers you question or at least gives you an idea.